# how to run two seperate independent programs(say "a.py" and "b.py") parallely from another program(say "c.py") in python using multi-threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

We have 2 independent programs called 'a.py' and 'b.py'.We need to run both of them in two seperate threads from another program called 'c.py'. Is this possible? If then, How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you only need to wrap the code of your files in a function (e.g `main()`) and then use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) or [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) modules to execute them concurrently.

Let's say your files are in this format:

```
# a.py

def main():
    for i in xrange(10000):
        print 'A says: %d' % (i)
```

And:

```
# b.py

def main():
    for i in xrange(10000):
        print 'B says: %d' % (i)
```

Then you can execute these two files in parallel, in the following fashion:

```
# parallel.py
from multiprocessing import Process
import imp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    code_a = imp.load_source('code_a', 'a.py')
    code_b = imp.load_source('code_b', 'b.py')    

    p1 = Process(target=code_a.main)
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=code_b.main)
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

You'll get a result like this:

> ...
>   A says: 862
>   A says: 865
>   A says: 866
>   **B says: 222**
>   **B says: 223**
>   **B says: 224**
>   A says: 867
>   A says: 868
>   A says: 869
>   ...